# How to copy and paste groupings in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have some nested grouped rows of a table in different files that I need to move together, but whenever I copy & paste one of the tables, I lose all of my groupings and just get all of the visible and hidden data.  There are way too many rows for me to manually regroup them.  How can I paste data while maintaining the groupings?

Comment: Do you use Paste or Paste Special?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @harrymc I have tried all of the paste specials and the groupings do not remain in the pasted data

Comment: groups are part of the tab and not part of the data, so is copying the tab and then deleteing what you don;t need an option? Otherwise, you'll need some kind of VBA.

Comment: u can try to copy sheets instead ..

Comment: r-click  on sheet > move or copy

Comment: I don't think you can copy the grouping, you'll have to regroup in the destination.  If you just want to copy the visible cells try selecting the table, pressing `Ctrl+G` to open the _Go To_ dialog, click _Special_ at the bottom of the dialog and tick _Visible Cells Only_, then copy & paste.